# Understanding defaultRowPrefetch and defaultBatchValue in Oracle JDBC Driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have set defaultRowPrefetch to 40 and defaultBatchValue to 15 in my Connection Object. Now I run a 'single' query which should return a 'single' row.

```
// define database user/password
String dbUser = "mp";
String dbPassword = "mp2";
String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:1521:scorpian";
// specify the Properties object
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", dbUser);
props.put("password", dbPassword);
props.put("defaultRowPrefetch","40");
props.put("defaultBatchValue","15");
```

Will the driver wait till it have 15 queries to run or run my query immediately ?Also, Since my query have to return only a single row , then how defaultRowPrefetch size comes into the picture.

Comment: There is no such thing in JDBC itself. Are you specifically talking about the Oracle JDBC driver? If so, please illustrate this with code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i mentioned JDBC as underlying can be any driver. I did not wanted answer tied up with name of any driver. If behaviour of evry driver is not same in respective to my question, please tell me. In that case, please consider Orcale jdbc Type 4 driver.

Comment: This is a driver-specific thing, other JDBC drivers don't have properties called `defaultRowPrefetch` or `defaultBatchValue`, so your question is tightly coupled to the Oracle driver and can't be generalized to JDBC as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

defaultBatchValue is used in the context of DML batching. Since you're talking about queries that return rows I'm guessing that you're not doing JDBC DML batching at all and so this property isn't relevant. What is relevant is defaultRowPrefetch which tells the Oracle driver to fetch rows 40 by 40 (instead of the default which is 10). Given that you only care about the first row you can set the value to 1.

Comment: Thnx. The above example is a custom scenario to just to explain my doubt. I hv understood the `defaultBatchValue` part. But I still did not get `defaultRowPrefetch`. I don't want to change its value. Let it be 40. Now what happens ? Will only one row returned ? What about rest 39 ?

Comment: The driver will fetch the rows 40 by 40. Calling ResultSet.next() will iterate through the rows. If your query returns only one row then setting the defaultRowPrefetch to 1 or 40 won't make any difference. In general this parameters is only used when fetching large amount of rows over WAN in order to reduce the number of roundtrips.

Comment: So rest 39 rows wont even exist in my scenario ?